# payment gateway transfer/withdraw request from paystack to customers in flutter

Tags: flutter, payment-gateway, payment, payment-processing, payout

I am making app where parents and students look up for tutors and hire them. I have set different pricing for tutors. So when student/parent pay the teacher suppose 500 NGN. How  am I gonna make the tutor to request the withdraw/ transfer of money from paystack to his account. For making payments i am using package here is my code where student/parent pay the teacher. I just want tutor to make the withdraw/transfer request from paystack.

```
..setSecretKey("SECRET-KEY")
      ..setAmount(int.parse(widget.price + '00'))
      ..setReference(DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString())
      ..setCurrency("NGN")
      ..setEmail("hamsimirza1@gmail.com")
      ..setFirstName("Hammas")
      ..setLastName("Ali")
      ..setMetadata(
        {
          "custom_fields": [
            {
              "value": "snapTask",
              "display_name": "Payment to",
              "variable_name": "payment_to"
            }
          ]
        },
      )
      ..onSuccesful(_onPaymentSuccessful)
      ..onPending(_onPaymentPending)
      ..onFailed(_onPaymentFailed)
      ..onCancel(_onPaymentCancelled)
      ..initialize();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a separate app for the teachers so that they can upload their banking details and request payment.

Once the parent pays the fee you can update the wallet amount of the teacher (in your database). Whenever the teacher want payout you can use the bank details stored in the database and send API request or use their SDK to transfer the amount to the teachers bank A/C.

Flowchart:
Parents app
[image]

Teachers app
[image]

Note: Im not familiar with Paystack and im writing it in the assumtion it has provision to send money via API or SDK

Comment: well done! you did great job in explaining how payment works. I have been searching for solution since week but you have explained nicely and short.